# Wordpress Ajax not working

Tags: ajax, wordpress

I have updated wordpress 3.5.2 and using Elemen theme in my wordpress site.
The problem i am having is in **admin side Ajax functionality is not working**.
I have tried **disabling all the plugins but that has not helped** me till now.
I have used `define( 'CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS', false );` in wp-config.php,
but even that hasn't been working for me.

by using console what error i got is like this

```
TypeError: switchEditors is undefined Source File: test.com/wp- admin/post.php?post=761&action=edit#category-pop Line: 1
```

i dont know how to solve this.

Please guide me now what should i check to work it in my favor.

Comment: show us your code..Show how are you sending and handling ajax request!!

Comment: its basic ajax that adds tag when entered, switching between visual editor and text , adding feature image any one of this not working.

Comment: if the core ajax is broken and you haven't edited core files and you have disabled plugins it is almost certainly a theme issue.  probably a javascript conflict. hard to say more unless you provide some real info though.

Comment: more info is needed before getting to any kind of conclusion.